# Shell and tty driver. Equivalent?

Tags: shell, tty

If I'm not wrong, tty is composed of:

- Line discipline
- TTY driver

In addition, a shell (bash, for example) is a program that execute different commands/programs like ls, mkdir, rm, ...

After reading [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con), I guess the shell is the same as TTY driver, because they share some features like job control, but I'm not sure at all.

So, are the shell and tty driver equivalent?

Please, correct me if something I wrote is wrong.

Comment: Yes, but the information given by @Kusalananda was essential for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4132/116858) again. A TTY is a terminal device, the shell is a command line interpreter (or "command *language* interpreter"). These are two very distinct things. A TTY doesn't have job control.

From the POSIX Base Definitions:

> **Terminal (or Terminal Device)**;
> A character special file that obeys the specifications of [the general terminal interface](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11).
>
> **Command Language Interpreter**;
> An interface that interprets sequences of text input as commands. It may operate on an input stream or it may interactively prompt and read commands from a terminal. It is possible for applications to invoke utilities through a number of interfaces, which are collectively considered to act as command interpreters. The most obvious of these are the `sh` utility and the `system()` function, although `popen()` and the various forms of `exec` may also be considered to behave as interpreters.

Comment: Note that `system()` and `popen()` do invoke `sh` to parse the command line provided to them.